# VSCode ignoring breakpoints during debug in python

Tags: python, django, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm trying to debug a Django project with VSCode. 
Everything works fine, I get the output and VSCode footer goes purple (debug mode) but it just ignores the breakpoints.

- I'm working on **WSL** (vscode remote)
- Python 3.6.9 (virtualenv)
- VSCode 1.43 (using Python and Python for VSCode extensions)

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
  "name": "Django",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "stopOnEntry": false,
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bullfrogloader/manage.py",
    "args": [
        "runserver",
    ]
},
]
}
```

This is an screenshot of vscode running it, just in case you see something weird there:

[image]

thank you so much guys, I just don't know what else to do.

Comment: Can you try the latest version of the debugger? https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/2104. If that doesn't work then please file a bug at that repository.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried change the launch.json, by adding "justMyCode": false

Comment: doesn't help. still ignoring breakpoints